# Using Memcache Directly in Laravel 5 instead of using through Cache

Tags: laravel, memcached

I am using local memcache server for storing values. It works fine if I go through defining Memcache as selected driver for Cache. in config/cache.php However, if I use memcache outside laravel the memcache accessing is much faster than within Laravel controllers using Cache::get( ).

I need to store decent amount of data in Memcache and will be accessed across the system. So I was trying to use memcache directly but I am getting Following error.

[2016-08-23 14:11:19] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Memcache' not found in....

My Code is as following :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Cache;
use stdClass;
use DB;
use Memcache;


class InternalCommunication extends Controller
{
        public function update_stock_prices_memcache()
        {
                 echo "\n before the memcache obj creation ".microtime(true);
                 $memcache = new Memcache();
                 $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
                 //$res1 = $memcache->set('key1',"Some value 2");
                 $res1 = $memcache->get('key1');
.....
```

Just to be clear - memcache packages are installed and working fine, as I could get it working via Cache: as well as directly accessing memcache from outside Laravel installation. 
Appreciate any sort of help I can get.

Comment: `new \Memcache;`?

Comment: Yes, tried. Same error :( I am using PHP7 , Laravel 5.2 and I have already installed memcached and php70-php-pecl-memcache packages.

Answer (score 0):

As per laravel [cache docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache), you need to set memcached configuration in `config/cache.php`, and specify driver to use as "memcached".

Then, simply use `\Cache` as below example.

```
// to get value
$value = \Cache::get('key');

// to set value
$minuts = 30;
\Cache::put('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

You could also specify driver on your code if have multiple caches

```
$value = \Cache::store('memcached')->get('key');
```

Comment: This is already working for me. My problem is it takes about 20 ms to access the Cache data. If I do the same outside laravel - it works much faster. Thus want to know how to use Memcache Directly.

Comment: i see, but i believe it should work correctly instead of having 20ms delay

Comment: It works correctly. As I mentioned, I have working solution but doesn't fit into the system with such high access delays. I need to store 1000s of keys which will be updating in real time - like every 15-20 seconds. So need this cache put and get faster. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the required changes needed to access the memcache within Laravel. Following is the code that is working smoothly for me now.

```
use Memcached;
        ....
        $memcache = new Memcached;
        $memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
        $res1 = $memcache->get('key1');
        ....
```

This is definitely faster than Cache::get using memcache driver!